# A timer event for dash in Python

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I am using Dash to build a GUI for sending data to a remote server.
The update process is asynchronic - as the data could take time to load.
After the user presses a button on the dash GUI it saves the data on the remote server as a CSV file, and once the file is saved it tells the server (using an API) to start running the upload process.
I would like to show the user the progress of the upload using a callback that will fire every 5 seconds.
I couldn't find any documentation on Dash's web site regarding this type of callback.
Is there any method for firing a callback every X seconds?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I found the answer on Dash's forums. The element is called an "interval".

Here is a working example which triggers an event every 5 seconds:

```
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import dash

app = dash.Dash()

app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Interval(id='interval1', interval=5 * 1000, n_intervals=0),
    html.H1(id='label1', children='')
])


@app.callback(dash.dependencies.Output('label1', 'children'),
    [dash.dependencies.Input('interval1', 'n_intervals')])
def update_interval(n):
    return 'Intervals Passed: ' + str(n)

app.run_server(debug=False, port=8050)
```